# data model for C 2 C business

Tags: mysql, database-design

I would like to find out what table relation would be idea for this case a Customer to Customer business transaction where one client provides a service to another for a charge. So this is purely a service C2C and no physical products involved. Examples of services include Math tutor lessons, yoga lessons, plumbing, piano lessons, karate lessons, art lessons, housekeeping etc.

Assumptions:
1. A transaction by a buying customer can contain multiple service (job) from the same seller customer.
2. A single (same) transaction from a buyer customer cannot contain multiple services (jobs) from multiple seller Customers.

What would be the idea data model for this case? What tables would I need, and what relationships between the tables would satisfy the stated case and assumptions?

```
Buyer 1->> transaction 1->> transaction_detail <<-1 jobs <<-1 Seller
```

I tried the above relationship with 1->> = one-to-many, making table transaction_detail a many-to-many table between the transaction table and job table. But this design allows for a transaction to contain multiple items from different sellers as shown below:

```
 +-------------+------------+--------+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| Buyer_First | Buyer_Last | job_id | trans_id | JOB           | Seller_First | Seller_Last |
+-------------+------------+--------+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
| Peter       | griffin    |     23 |      14 | English Tutor | Wei          | Tei         |
| Peter       | griffin    |     32 |      14 | Chinese tutor | Ping         | Wang        |
+-------------+------------+--------+---------+---------------+--------------+-------------+
```

We can clearly see that transaction 14 contains two jobs from two different sellers, which is against our assumptions set above.

Any ideas?

Comment: *But this design allows for a transaction to contain multiple items from different sellers as shown below* It is 2 separate transactions. And each of them is to have unique `trans_id`.

Comment: It is the same transaction, 14, containing two jobs. trans_id and job_id are foreign key fields in the transaction_detail table. What exactly are you saying?

Comment: *It is the same transaction, 14, containing two jobs* They are dependent? for example, ejecting one of them automatically ejects another one? If so you're right.

Comment: job_id 23 and 32 belong to different Sellers, which means they should be in the same transaction/order/deal.

Comment: Again... some buyer want to buy 2 services of two different sellers. You start the transaction. You try to store first job... and it fails (for example, not enough cash - the buyer is blind). Will you try to store second job or not (buyer's cash is enough for this job)?

Comment: I do not want a buyer to buy more than one service from two or more different sellers. Each buyer can only deal with one seller for any given transaction.

Comment: What it a transaction in your case? **One payment** (or payment intention - it doesn't matter) from one buyer to one seller? If so, how the transaction can consist from two "jobs" and so from **two payments**? Sorry, I cannot understand your logic.

Comment: Transaction = order.

Comment: Sorry... maybe somebody else will understand. I cannot...

Comment: Separate table for people.